# Trying to move UIImageView on UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uiviewanimation

Hi Guys I am trying to move UIImageView using the following code on UIPanGestureRecognizer

```
 CGPoint pointMove;
 pointMove.x = holderView.center.x + (currentPoint.x - lastPoint.x);
 pointMove.y = holderView.center.y + (currentPoint.y - lastPoint.y);

 holderView.center = pointMove;

 lastPoint = currentPoint;
```

But this is giving a jumble on moving not moving smoothly.
Please help me

Comment: See if this helps you. http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/

Comment: Thanks buddy but I am looking for something in my present code

Comment: Alright. I hope you got what you are looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this in your code.

```
  CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[holderView superview]];

    [holderView setCenter:CGPointMake([piece center].x + translation.x, [piece center].y + translation.y)];
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

i got a best example of Dragging Image using `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

please download this demo and check it :-

https://github.com/elc/iCodeBlogDemoPhotoBoard

hope it's help's you

here are some same Asked Question please visit link:-

[Drag + Rotation using UIPanGestureRecognizer touch getting off track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10181255/drag-rotation-using-uipangesturerecognizer-touch-getting-off-track)

[swapping images using pan gesture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794731/swapping-images-using-pan-gesture)

[How to use UIPanGestureRecognizer to move object? iPhone/iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672677/how-to-use-uipangesturerecognizer-to-move-object-iphone-ipad)